# Can you kill a Tarrasque with the Open Hand monk's Quivering Palm feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, class-feature, monk

I see the [Tarrasque](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/tarrasque) has Legendary Resistance so it can pass failed saving throws. It has a list of Legendary Actions 3 times a day. I keep seeing people say to keep making it do saves to get rid of the Legendary Resistance even though it is not listed under the limited Legendary actions.

Since the [Way of the Open Hand monk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/monk#WayoftheOpenHand)'s Quivering Palm technique relies on failing a Constitution save to instantly reduce the target to 0 HP, can Quivering Palm kill a Tarrasque?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### A Monk's Quivering Palm could kill the Tarrasque after it has used all its Legendary Resistances.

The Tarrasque's Legendary Resistance is limited to 3 per day.  This limit is listed with the Legendary Resistance Trait, not with the Legendary Actions:

> Legendary Resistance (3/Day): If the tarrasque fails a saving throw, it can choose to succeed instead.

Once all three uses have been expended, the Tarrasque would be reduced to 0 Hit Points if it failed the saving throw for a Monk's Quivering Palm.

Comment: You may want to clarify that the Tarrasque still has to fail the save or it just takes 10d10 necrotic damage. With a +10 Constitution modifier, getting a 19 (what the save DC would be with 20 Wisdom and no magic items) isn't that difficult for the Tarrasque, especially considering he has Magic Resistance so burning through Legendary Resistances will be very difficult.

Comment: @DavidCoffron is Quivering Palm considered a magical effect? Otherwise Tarrasque doesn't benefit from Magic Resistance trait.

Comment: @AntiDrondert I understood that, but there are not many effects that the Tarrasque would *have* to succeed against that *arent* magical making it even more difficult to get rid of the Legendary Resistances *before* using Quivering Palm

Comment: Therefore, use a team of 4 or more Quivering Palm monks. :)

Comment: Monk abilities are not considered magical unless they specifically say they are (way of the four elements) so magical resistance would not apply: [Does ki count as magic for the purpose of an antimagic field, or is it only fluff?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76005/does-ki-count-as-magic-for-the-purpose-of-an-antimagic-field-or-is-it-only-fluf)

Comment: The point is just that it can save its Legendary Resistance for the monk abilities because Magic Resistance works against other effects.

Comment: Makes me wonder what the odds of an open palm monk soloing a tarrasque would be. You'd need to land 4 hits and have the tarrasque fail the save, but if you have the mobile feat you should be able to easily kite it without getting hit yourself.